# Can you convert this code to monad comprehensions using Arrow FX?

Tags: kotlin, project-reactor, arrow-kt

Can you convert this reactive method to an [Arrow Fx Project Reactor monad comprehension](https://arrow-kt.io/docs/io-integrations/reactor/)?

```
class ApplicationServiceImpl(private val applicationRepository: ApplicationRepository,
                             private val clientRepository: ClientRepository) : ApplicationService {

    override fun findByProjectId(clientId: String, projectId: String): Flux<ApplicationOut> {
        return clientRepository.findById(clientId)
                .switchIfEmpty(ClientDoesntExistException(clientId).toMono())
                .flatMapMany { client ->
                    applicationRepository.findByProjectIdOrderByNameAsc(projectId).map {
                        it.convertToApplicationOut(client.timeZone)
                    }
                }
    }

}
```

I've tried something like this but it isn't valid.

The first problem I've found is, originally I converted a Mono to a Flux using flatMapMany. If I use `FluxK.monad().fx.monad`  `clientRepository.findById(clientId).k().bind()` doesn't have a `.bind()` function available.

If I use `MonoK.monad().fx.monad` instead I don't know how to convert the output to a Flux:

```
    override fun findByProjectId(clientId: String, projectId: String): Flux<out ApplicationOut> {

        return FluxK.monad().fx.monad {
            val client = clientRepository.findById(clientId).k().bind()
            if (client != null) {
                !applicationRepository.findByProjectIdOrderByNameAsc(projectId)
                        .map { it.convertToApplicationOut(client.timeZone) }.k()
            } else {
                throw !ClientDoesntExistException(clientId).toMono<ApplicationOut>().k()
            }
        }.fix().flux
```

**UPDATE**

Following El Paco's answer I've modified the code to:

```
        return FluxK.monad().fx.monad {
            val client = !clientRepository.findById(clientId).toFlux().k()
            if (client != null) {
                !applicationRepository.findByProjectIdOrderByNameAsc(projectId)
                        .map { it.convertToApplicationOut(client.timeZone) }.k()
            } else {
                !ClientDoesntExistException(clientId).toFlux<ApplicationOut>().k()
            }
        }.fix().flux
```

It works fine when `clientRepository.findById(clientId)` exists. When it doesn't, instead of assigning null to val client, it exits the comprehension (else isn't executed) so I can't launch my exception from inside the comprehension, which I guess is normal.

Consider the following method, in which I need to control two situations where the client or the project don't exist:

```
    return clientRepository.findById(clientId)
            .switchIfEmpty(ClientDoesntExistException(clientId).toMono())
            .flatMapMany { client ->
                applicationRepository.findByProjectIdOrderByNameAsc(projectId)
                        .switchIfEmpty(ClientDoesntExistException(projectId).toMono())
                        .map { it.convertToApplicationOut(client.timeZone) }
            }
```

How can I deal with those non-existence cases when using comprehensions, taking into account that the if/else approach doesnt work?

I can use the switchIfEmpty operator outside the comprehension but I wouldn't know the cause (client doesn't exist vs project doesn't exist)

```
    return FluxK.monad().fx.monad {
        val client = !clientRepository.findById(clientId).toFlux().k()
        !applicationRepository.findByProjectIdOrderByNameAsc(projectId)
              .map { it.convertToApplicationOut(client.timeZone) }.k()        
    }.fix().flux
            .switchIfEmpty(XXX)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should convert all operations to Flux then, in your case `clientRepository.findById(clientId).toFlux().k()`

Also, you don't need to throw that exception to break the chain.

```
!ClientDoesntExistException(clientId).toMono<ApplicationOut>().k()
```

Comment: I appreciate your taking the time to answer this. I've updated the question with some doubts about how to handle switchIfEmpty

Comment: SwitchIfEmpty is a Stream operator that's not on Arrow yet. You could get the same behavior by collecting to a list with `Flux.of` if not empty and binding an error otherwise.